# Cut, Copy Paste keyboard shortcut problem on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, shortcuts, copy, desktop-icons, paste

I have just installed ubuntu 20.04 on my dektop and when I tried to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>shortcuts to cut/copy/paste a file/text/folder etc nothing happened. I checked the keyboard shortcuts on settings, but none of them was appropriate. I also tried to create custom shortcuts for those, but it also did not work. I have searched all of the related answered questions and videos but none of them applied to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be this bug, which still is in 20.04 also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183

Comment: Just FYI: `Ctrl`+`x` does imply `Ctrl`+`c`.